# LWJGL shading textured rects, how to rotate mask?

Tags: java, rotation, textures, shader, lwjgl

I have been learning how to use shaders in lwjgl. Now i have ran into an issue, where i need to rotate my mask for shading to get different results. How can i modify the mask transformation/rotation after it is bind, or do i need to modify it before. I tried almost anything but couldn't find an existing question / instructions. Any help will be greatly appreciated! This is my code for drawing a textured rectangle using my custom shader program.

```
    private static void drawTexture(int shaderProgram, int texID1, int texID2) {

    glUseProgram(shaderProgram);

    setTextureUnits(shaderProgram);

    bindTextures(texture1.getTextureID(), texture2.getTextureID(), mask.getTextureID());

        glBegin(GL11.GL_QUADS);

            glColor3f(1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f);
            glTexCoord2f(0,0);
            glVertex2f(-0.5f,-0.5f);

            glColor3f(1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f);
            glTexCoord2f(1,0);
            glVertex2f(+0.5f,-0.5f);

            glColor3f(1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f);
            glTexCoord2f(1,1);
            glVertex2f(+0.5f,+0.5f);

            glColor3f(1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f);
            glTexCoord2f(0,1);
            glVertex2f(-0.5f,+0.5f);

        glEnd();

    glUseProgram(0);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the answer to my own question:

create a matrix2 variable, and rotate the textCoords of your mask. the -+0.5's are for rotate around center. To fix any issues like exposed corners, clamp your textures on to the edge.

**shader:**

```
mat2 textureMatrix = mat2(cos(angle), sin(angle), -sin(angle), cos(angle));

float mask = texture2D(mask, textureMatrix*(gl_TexCoord[0].xy-0.5)+0.5).a;
```